# Correct options for keeping open a reverse SSH-tunnel using autossh

Tags: ssh, ldap, tunnel

I have a set-up with a LDAP-sever (`ldapserver`) behind a strict firewall, and a webapplication running on a sever (`appserver`) outside that firewall that needs to authenticate using that LDAP-sever.

I have successfully used a third server (`tunnelserver`) as in intermediate, setting up a SSH-tunnel between `appserver` and `ldapserver` by running the following command on `tunnelserver`:

```
ssh username@appserver -R 28420:ldapserver:389
```

The only issue is that occasionally I get a broken pipe, and lose the SSH-tunnel.

A solution seems [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), but my limited SSH-knowledge barely managed to get the tunnel working, and seems insufficient to correctly respecify the options for `autossh`.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameters are basically the same (`autossh` passes them directly to `ssh`). Remove `-f` if you don't want `autossh` to background itself. You probably want the `-N` option to not execute a shell on the server. Select a free port for the `-M` option (the port one above that must also be free). On Debian/Ubuntu you can omit this because the package includes a wrapper script which automatically selects a free port.

```
autossh -M 20000 -f -N -R 28420:ldapserver:389 username@appserver
```

Comment: My autossh won't start without a -M option, is that required here?

Comment: @EightBitTony Ah, the Debian/Ubuntu package includes a wrapper script which automatically selects a monitoring port.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in 2013 that using autossh for reverse tunnels that the remote side sshd was not being terminated.

I worked around this via script to start/stop/restart my tunnel (which i included with @reboot in crontab to start the tunnel), wherein I would kill the remote end using ssh forced command i.e. when stopping (or restarting) the tunnel.